# Чем конструкция switch плоха?

Tags: switch

Не раз слышал что конструкция `switch` это плохо. Например вот в этой [статье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/169139/), пункт 10 Но ни разу не слышал почему и когда он плох. Кто что думает по этому поводу?

Comment: Личное предвзятое мнение:  
Если код нормально оформлен отступами, то он лучше усваивается, если использовать if, а не switch.  
Если же автор кода не знает, что вложенные блоки надо отступать 4-мя пробелами, то пусть использует switch, а лучше вообще ничего не пишет.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать спасибо я наверное именно о таких примерах  плохого switch слышал

Comment: Сишный switch весьма хитрая штучка. И есть даже пример использования его ненормальности http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.143.9245&rep=rep1&type=pdf (одно из оснований ОС Contiki)

Comment: @Котик: в виду развернувшейся дискуссии, может быть, превратите в ответ?

Comment: @VladD Готово.

Comment: @Котик: спасибо!

Comment: Нет ничего плохого, если этот инструмент правильно использовать

Comment: @danpetruk Люблю такие комменты ради комментирования.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Когда говорят про плохие `switch,` обычно имеют ввиду [примеры следующего рода.](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism)
- Другое дело, что, в принципе, в конструкции `switch` как таковой нет ничего плохого и не стоит сразу же реплейсить все `switch'и` в своем коде на сложные иерархии классов. В тех случаях, когда такой рефакторинг действительно оправдан, **вопросов возникать не должно.**

Comment: `Тот же самый PropertyScanner.scan() при желании может быть переписан через AbstractState и визиторы, не применяя goto. Не знаю, хорошее это получилось бы решение или нет, но факт имеет место быть.` 1) Если ты не знаешь получится ли хорошее решение или нет, то как можно знать что факту (факт != предположение) есть место быть? 2) Не надо пускать пыль в глаза: `AbstractState` <- это что вообще? Абстрактное состояние/класс? AbstractState - если это класс, он может нарушить **Liskov Substitution Principle** т.к дилема `is-a` будет нарушена (речь о `PropertyScanner.php`).

Comment: `Сказали goto не применять?` Что дальше? Где факты? Все, всегда что-то говорят. Например все говорят, что **Синглтон** это не **АНТИ-ПАТТЕРН**, Что в MVC - Model это один класс, View это html файлы, Controller - мост между моделью и видом.

Comment: @heavy_metal_fan: А вы всё же почитайте аргументацию Дейкстры против `goto`. Каких именно фактов вы хотите? (Приведу лишь первое предложение:)

> For a number of years I have been familiar with the observation that the quality of programmers is a decreasing function of the density of go to statements in the programs they produce.

Comment: >Где факты?

А за фактами далеко ходить не нужно. Достаточно того, что в грамотном, хорошо продуманном и эффективном коде встретить `goto` практически нереально. И исчезающие единичные случаи удачного применения картину не меняют. А вот если зайти на какой-нибудь говнокод, то там этого `goto` сколько угодно :)

Comment: @heavy_metal_fan

- Я не понимаю, вы спорите ради спора? Зачем придираться к словам и что вообще вы пытаетесь доказать?

- Я утверждаю следующее — применение `GOTO` можно считать допустимым в некотором конечном числе сценариев. Перед применением `goto` в каждом из этих сценариев необходимо рассмотреть возможные альтернативы (можно формально доказать, что программа с `GOTO` может быть равносильна переписана без использования `GOTO`) и **в том и только в том случае,** когда вариант с `GOTO` кажется более изящным, использовать его.

- Не понял, как `MVC`, `html` файлы и мосты относятся к теме.

Comment: - Теперь конкретно про пример с `PropertyScanner.scan()`. Если вы не поняли семантику `AbstractState` из названия, то не надо начинать говорить что-то про принцип подстановки Лисков. Я предложил несложную идею рефакторинга кода `PropertyScanner.scan()`: в текущем варианте вся логика конечного автомата сканнера расположена в одном единственном методе, а переходы между состояниями выполяются с помощью `GOTO` в пределах этого метода.

Comment: - Ничто не мешает ввести набор классов состояний автомата (`AbstractState` и его наследники в моей терминоголии), организовать между ними **явные переходы** а дальше сравнить написанный код с кодом, содержащим `GOTO`. Я не могу однозначно сказать, стало бы лучше или хуже, но факт того, что такой подход *стоит как минимум попробовать,*  имеет место быть.

- Естественно, что набор отдельных классов, каждый из которых соответствует какому-то состоянию `ДКА`, ни в коей мере не нарушает принцип `is-a`.

Answer (score 8):

На самом деле предубеждение к `switch` существует с тех времен, когда компиляторы были неоптимизирующими. Тогда `switch` превращался в огромный набор условных операторов, что нельзя назвать лучшим решением. Зато выглядело это аккуратнее, чем такой же набор if'ов в исходном коде программе. Сейчас же компилятор, когда видит `switch` использует либо дерево из условных переходов (что-то в духе [такого](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0611037.pdf), см. [также](http://file:///home/gaal/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8/10.1.1.69.7532.pdf)), либо использует таблицу переходов. В последнем случае создается таблица вида <index>:<адрес перехода> из которой выбирается нужный адрес, по которому лежит соответствующий индексу код. Можно догадаться, что это существенно эффективнее, чем сравнивать каждое значение соответствующего `case`. Так что теперь `switch` не очень страшен.

С другой стороны, при использовании конструкции `switch`-`case` не нужно забывать про особенности работы с ключевыми словами `break` и `default`. Некоторые забывают, например, слово `break` и в результате имеют некорректное выполнение программы (выполняется не только нужный `case`, но и последующие, пока не встретится `break`)

Что еще хочу сказать. switch хорошо работает с константными целыми или перечислимыми типами. В этом случае компилятор даже может подсказать, что есть проблема. Например, с помощью предупреждения.

Например, для gcc:

```
-Wswitch
    Warn whenever a switch statement has an index of enumerated type and lacks a case for one or more of the named codes of that enumeration. (The presence of a default label prevents this warning.) case labels outside the enumeration range also provoke warnings when this option is used (even if there is a default label). This warning is enabled by -Wall.

-Wswitch-default
    Warn whenever a switch statement does not have a default case.

-Wswitch-enum
    Warn whenever a switch statement has an index of enumerated type and lacks a case for one or more of the named codes of that enumeration. case labels outside the enumeration range also provoke warnings when this option is used. The only difference between -Wswitch and this option is that this option gives a warning about an omitted enumeration code even if there is a default label.
```

Comment: >Тогда switch превращался в огромный набор условных операторов

IMHO, таблицы переходов - одна из самых древних конструкций, применявшаяся ещё во времена цара Гороха... Вообще интересно было бы раскопать какие-нибудь замшелые компиляторы и проверить :)

Comment: P.S. Проверил TC 1.01 (1990), таблица переходов :) Древней под рукой нет.

Answer (score 4):

Плохость или хорошесть конструкции `switch` зависит от того во что ее превращает компилятор. Проиллюстрирую в псевдокоде:

Конструкция `switch`

```
switch(i) {
case 0: do0;
case 1: do1;
case 2: do2;
default: doDefault;
}
```

может превратиться, либо в (вариант №1):

```
if(i==0)
   do0;
else if(i==1)
   do1;
else if(i==2)
   do2;
else
   doDefault;
```

или же в (вариант №2):

```
switch(i) {
0: do0;
1: do1;
2: do2;
default: doDefault;
}
```

Отличие состоит в том, что в первом варианте с `if-else` условие проверяется каждый раз, а во втором условие проверяется 1 раз создается таблица переходов.

Очевидно, что 2-й вариант реализации быстрее и удобнее. Скажем в Java все [именно так и устроено](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.10). Да и вообще в более-менее любом нормальном современном компиляторе так и устроено.

В древних компиляторах часто реализовывалось через 1-ю конструкцию `if-else` - оттуда видимо и предубеждение против `switch`

Comment: @Barmaley Я уже писал, что сишный switch весьма интересная штука. Он может управление передавать внутрь блоков извне, т.е.

    switch(i) {
    case 0: break;
            {
            int i;
    case 1: break;
            }
    };

Ежели мне склероз не изменяет. См. реализацию protothreads на компиляторах не-gcc.