# Альтернатива if PHP

Tags: php

Я любитель в программировании, весь мой код сводится к сплошным if/else, как только дело доходит до просмотра и сравнения значений. Иногда даже весь код делится на ветвление if'а и то что в нем. В результате это смотрится очень некрасиво, да и скорее всего не рационально. Есть ли альтернативы? Либо такой подход является нормальным?

Comment: Думаете профессионалы пишут без if'ов ?

Comment: Нужно смотреть конкретные случае скорее... по коду.....иногда бывает лучше применить switch....... но в целом - зависит же от задачи и от того, что и из чего делаете

Comment: Во-первых, это нормально - все использую в условиях if-else. Во-вторых, есть условия, где, скажем, `switch` более к месту.

Comment: Если рассматриваются различные логические ситуации, то я думаю что Ваш подход нормален. Но для разнообразия и общего развития можете посмотреть про http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.elseif.php и switch.

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron, но по ссылке же про один if и идет :)

Comment: Возможно, вам нужно вот это: [Чем конструкция switch плоха?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/214920/10105).

Comment: @Grundy именно! Но там разнообразный if. Возможно разнообразив свой if-подход тс почувствует моральное удоволетворение )

Comment: If - отстой , If уже устарел. скучный оператор на самом деле
Запомните код с IF смотрится очень уныло и неитересно

Answer (score 2):

Подход, если работает – нормальный. Альтернативы есть:

**Тройной оператор**, сокращённая форма if-else

```
логическое_значение ?  значение_если_true : значение_если_false
```

Например:

```
$result = 1 > 2 ? 'больше' : 'меньше';  // "меньше"

$result = $param ?: 'по-умолчанию'; // задание дефолтного значения
// если в $param что-то есть, то $result примет это значение,
// а если значение $param приводится к логическому false,
// то $result примет значение "по-умолчанию"

echo '<a href="/about"' . ($page=='about' ? ' class="active"' : '') . '>about</a>';
```

**Конструкцией switch-case** удобно заменить множественные if-elseif-elseif:

```
switch( $bukva) {
  case 'a':
    function_a();
    $result = "Result A";
    break;
  case 'b':
    function_b();
    break;
  case 'c':
    function_c();
    break;
  case 'd':
    function_d();
    break;
  default:
    echo "делаем что-то, в остальных случаях";
}
```

Comment: Только не тройной, а тернарный.

Comment: – Тернарный одеколон, пожалуйста! : )    "Ternary" – это буквально «тройной». Не вижу необходимости использовать заимствованное слово там, где есть полный эквивалент в родном языке.

Comment: Главное не забывать о маленькой особенности вложенных тернарных операторов: http://habrahabr.ru/post/114899/

Comment: @Sergiks, и ты сам себе противоречишь произнося "эквивалент". Умного человека отличает не только способность решать сложные задачи и давать правильные, но и соблюдать общие конвенции. Чего и вам желаю.

Comment: @ZhukovRoman с каких пор мы на «ты»? И где определена конвенция, регулирующая перевод на русский язык термина "ternary operator"?

Comment: @Sergiks могу писать "вы", и даже "Вы", если это изменит смысл этой беседы. Конвенцию можете прочитать первым результатом поисковика по запросу "тройной оператор".

Comment: @ZhukovRoman соглашусь, что слово «тернарный» используется часто. И отнесу это на счёт слабости переводчиков и лени копирующих. «Шаурма» или «шаверма»? : ) Тройной, троичный, третичный, триадный, тройственный?

Answer (score 0):

Есть ещё оператор switch, более подробнее Вы найдёте по [этой ссылке](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.switch.php), но прошу заметить, что не всегда он подходит для выполнения задачи.

Comment: Да ещё можете воспользоваться альтернативным синтаксисом if/else: http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 0):

Внутри циклов существуют операторы break (выход из цикла) и (переход к следующему шагу цикла), внутри функций - оператор return (хотя злоупотреблять им нежелательно).