# Можно ли уменьшить кол-во switch'ей?

Tags: c#, .net, инспекция-кода

В общем, имею такую иерархию:

Режимы сохранения:

```
public enum SaveConfigMode
{
    Mode1,
    Mode2,
    Mode3
}
```

Базовый класс для режимов сохранения, где каждый наследник этого класса имеет свой уникальный набор полей:

```
public abstract class SaveConfigBase
{
   public SaveConfigMode SaveConfigMode { get; protected set; }

    protected SaveConfigBase(SaveConfigMode saveConfigMode)
    {
        SaveConfigMode = saveConfigMode;
    }
}
```

Каждое значение enum имеет по одному наследнику.

Главная конфигурация, которая имеет свой набор полей(его не отобразил), а так же хранит в себе параметры сохранения

```
public class MainConfig
{
    SaveConfigBase SaveConfig;
}
```

Соответственно, так как я храню в конфиге базовый тип, то с ним никак не могу работать и приходится прогонять его через свичи с последующим приведением типа.

На текущий момент у меня 3 места, где я должен воспользоваться свичами:

1 и 2 - это сериализация и десириализация, которую я делаю руками (так надо)
Т.е я получил на вход MainConfig, сериализовал/десериализовал его поля, а потом посылаю поле SaveConfigBase в отдельный метод сериализатора, где через switch перебираю значения, чтобы привести SaveConfigBase к конкретному классу и вызвать нужный метод сериализации/десериализации.

3 - это фабрика, которая на основании этого перечисления создаст мне необходимую реализацию класса

Можно ли чего-то придумать или это наиболее оптимальное решение?

Comment: `это наиболее оптимальное решение?` - "это" это что? Вы ж не показали ни проблему, ни решение. Вы показали пару непонятно как связанных с вашей проблемой классов.

Comment: А у вас есть однозначное соответствие между реальным (неабстрактным) классом и значением SaveConfigMode?

Comment: @VladD Да, на каждое значение enum есть наследник от абстрактного класса.

Comment: @tym32167 ну проблема в том, что 1)Чтобы работать нужно свичится по и приводить типы 2)Если захожу добавить еще тип, то придется в нескольких местах править свичи.

Comment: Один из стандартных рефакторингов: преобразовать перечисление в классы. То есть сделать классы наподобие `SaveConfigMode1`, `SaveConfigMode2` и т. д.

Comment: @iluxa1810: А зачем вам тогда сам enum? Может, выкинуть его, и заменить на виртуальные методы? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/214920/10105

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Фишка в том, что классы _уже_ и так есть, надо просто выкинуть сам enum, а код веток свитча сделать виртуальными функциями.

Comment: @VladD Не хотелось бы возлагать на классы ответственность за сериализацию.

Comment: Enum, возможно, понадобиться. Просто, я его бинжу еще на Combobox в интерфейсе и на его основании отображаю тот или иной GroupBox на которых забинжен свой наследик от базовго класса.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Понимаю. Но тогда можно всё равно попробовать выкинуть enum, а вместо switch (enumValue) сделать pattern-matching.

Comment: Зачем перечисление, если у вас есть типы ему соответствующие? Дублирование данных плохо. А вообще рабочий пример бы увидеть. Типы тоже можно использовать в свичах, при том сразу с приведением, свич поддерживает паттерн матчинг.

Comment: Для выбора UI по конкретному классу можно ж тоже использовать `<ResourceDictionary><DataTemplate DataType="Derived1">...</DataTemplate><DataTemplate DataType="Derived2">...</DataTemplate>...`

Comment: @VladD у меня WinForms, но в теории, наверное, могу 1 раз раскошелиться на рефлексию, чтобы найти всех наследников и на их основании сделать бинды.

Comment: Может, [пригодится](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/enumeration-classes-over-enum-types). И там ссылки в конце.

Comment: @iluxa1810: С WinForms не знаю, но да, один раз рефлексия должна решить. Это недорого.